# Can I delete database form wp-admin wordpress?

Tags: database, wordpress, admin

I want to delete my existing wordpress database and upload new wordpress database. I have access of wp-admin but not have access of cpanel.  Can I delete my existing database? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: there will be away to delete it via some plugins. But then you would have no access to upload a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know you have to use some plugins to do that. Wordpress does not include a tool to accomplish this.

Here is a plugin you may use: [WP-DBmanager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-dbmanager/)